# Can't get nginx reverse proxy to load css/images of web application

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've configured a reverse proxy, and while the http loads, the css/images of the login page don't load. It is trying to load them from the localhost and not the upstream server

I've tried multiple proxy_redirects and rewrites (although I'm fairly new at this) and can't seem to get it working.

```
 server {
  listen 80;
  location /test {
    proxy_pass https://10.10.10.10/platform/login;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect https://10.10.10.10/ /;
   }




}
```

Log error:

```
[error] 26072#0: *127 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/platform/images/leaves.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /platform/images/leaves.png HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/test"
```

When I inspect element on chrome it returns 404's for all css/images as well.

Please Help

Comment: Lots of causes out there for this, but try `proxy_pass https://10.10.10.10/platform/login/;`

Comment: @EternalHour its already in the first line. Do you mean the "/" at the end. I just tried it and there was no change

Comment: Yeah, the trailing slash.

Comment: @EternalHour No luck :/. Its looking for these files in the local nginx directory but not the upstream server that actually hosts the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your website's HTML is trying to access a url that is not `/test/**` but `/platform/images/leaves.png` this means that NGINX won't try to use the reverse proxy.

This part of your NGINX configuration is not getting used at all for anything but `/test/**`, and NGINX is searching on the local disk of the webserver for the files, which do not exist.

try using a config which captures all scopes instead of just /test.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /platform {
    proxy_pass https://10.10.10.10/platform/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect https://10.10.10.10/ /;
   }
}
```

your website should be visible from `http://{NGINX server}/platform/login`
this will change your end-point's url so you could add an exception for `/test` to make `http://{NGINX server}/test` work aswell.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location /platform {
    proxy_pass https://10.10.10.10/platform/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect https://10.10.10.10/ /;
   }
  location /test {
    proxy_pass https://10.10.10.10/platform/login;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect https://10.10.10.10/ /;
  }
}
```

You could also edit your HTML page and proxy_pass `/test/**` to `https://10.10.10.10/platform/`

your problem is further explained in [Nginx defaults to /usr/share/nginx/html](https://serverfault.com/questions/920880/nginx-defaults-to-usr-share-nginx-html)